# How to install mailer Lite pop up in the nuxt with this script extern ? Error window is not defined

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I want to install this popup on the nuxt.js application
My problem is?
if i want to add this script on my page is not work and the error is window is not defined

How I add this pop up to my applications Nuxt.js?

```
  <!-- MailerLite Universal -->
<script>
(function(m,a,i,l,e,r){ m['MailerLiteObject']=e;function f(){
var c={ a:arguments,q:[]};var r=this.push(c);return "number"!=typeof r?r:f.bind(c.q);}
f.q=f.q||[];m[e]=m[e]||f.bind(f.q);m[e].q=m[e].q||f.q;r=a.createElement(i);
var _=a.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];r.async=1;r.src=l+'?v'+(~~(new Date().getTime()/1000000));
_.parentNode.insertBefore(r,_);})(window, document, 'script', 'https://static.mailerlite.com/js/universal.js', 'ml');

var ml_account = ml('accounts', '3587348', 'o8w2i6n0n5', 'load');
</script>
<!-- End MailerLite Universal -->
```

take my error

WINDOW IS NOT DEFINED

```
pages/document.js:16:
Object../pages/document.js
webpack/bootstrap:25:
__webpack_require__
pages/index.js:24:76
Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
webpack/bootstrap:25:
__webpack_require__
webpack/bootstrap:25:
__webpack_require__
pages/index.vue:1:
Module../pages/index.vue
webpack/bootstrap:25:
__webpack_require__
async server.js:2289:21
```

Answer (score 0):

nuxt3 is **SSR** which means it render at server side and there is no window at server and nuxt show this error so you should ask nuxt after it loaded for client with this `process.client`.

for example :

```js
if(process.client){
  window.addEventListener();
} 
// => success :)
```